# Como unir dos consulta en sql para que me un total?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos estoy acá para solicitar de su importante contribución
tengo este Script

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(mes,0)[mes],
ISNULL(Cod_Area,0)[Codigo Area],
ISNULL(nom_emp,0)[Nombre Empleado],
ISNULL(Cod_Puesto,0)[Codigo Puesto],
ISNULL(Puesto,0)[Puesto],
ISNULL ([LENTES],0)[LENTES],
Fecha_Gestion,
ISNULL ([AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],0)[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],
Fecha_Gestion,
ISNULL ([DEFUNCION DE FAMILIA],0)[DEFUNCION DE FAMILIA],
Fecha_Gestion,
ISNULL ([AYUDA MATERNIDAD],0)[AYUDA MATERNIDAD],
Fecha_Gestion,
ISNULL ([AYUDA MEDICAMENTOS (R.L.)],0)[AYUDA MEDICAMENTOS (R.L.)],
 Fecha_Gestion
 FROM
 (SELECT m.mes,tp.Cod_Area,tp.Cod_Puesto,Puesto,     me.nom_emp,TB.Tipo_Benef,Monto,Fecha_Gestion
    FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp
    INNER JOIN Mes AS m ON M.id=TP.mes
    INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb ON TB.Id=TP.Tipo_Benef
    INNER JOIN Maestro_Empl AS me ON me.No_emp = tp.No_emp
    UNION ALL

) AS  TablaDatos
 PIVOT 
(
    SUM (Monto)
    FOR Tipo_Benef IN ([LENTES],[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],[DEFUNCION DE FAMILIA],[AYUDA MATERNIDAD],[AYUDA MEDICAMENTOS (R.L.)])
)AS PivotTable
 ;
```

que me da como resultado da [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abra una manera que de yo puedo sumar el total de cada una  los monto por mes ejemplo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No debería ser 350? ¿Y donde presentarías el monto total por mes, en un registro adicional? ¿Y qué hay de abril? ¿Donde iría el total para abril?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk) para elaborar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: en sintecis sacar un subtotal de los meses  en este caso de abril y marzo

Comment: @norma, para responder a un comentario, te recomiendo ingresar el caracter arroba "@" y luego el nombre del usuario al que deseas responderle. Aquí puedes ver mas [información relevante a los comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Si provees información de prueba en dbfiddle, otros usuarios pueden entender mejor la estructura de tu base de datos y así mismo podrán aportar tus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Lee un poco sobre *Windows Functions* de *SQL*. Puedes usar un `SUM` algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @tabla AS TABLE
( 
    campo1 INT,
    campo2 DATETIME,
    valor money 
)

INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-01-01' , 100);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-01-02' , 100);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-01-03' , 100);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-01-04' , 100);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-02-01' , 150);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-02-02' , 150);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-02-03' , 150);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-02-04' , 150);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-03-01' , 20);
INSERT INTO @tabla (campo1,campo2,valor)VALUES(1,'2017-03-01' , 20);

SELECT
    *,
    SUM(valor) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(campo2) ORDER BY campo2) opcion1, --acumulado
    SUM(valor) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(campo2) ORDER BY MONTH(campo2) RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) opcion2 --total del grupo
FROM @tabla
```

Tendrás un resultado como el siguiente:

```
   campo1         campo2           valor  opcion1 opcion2
 1   1     2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 100.00 100.00  400.00
 2   1     2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 100.00 200.00  400.00
 3   1     2017-01-03 00:00:00.000 100.00 300.00  400.00
 4   1     2017-01-04 00:00:00.000 100.00 400.00  400.00
 5   1     2017-02-01 00:00:00.000 150.00 150.00  600.00
 6   1     2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 150.00 300.00  600.00
 7   1     2017-02-03 00:00:00.000 150.00 450.00  600.00
 8   1     2017-02-04 00:00:00.000 150.00 600.00  600.00
 9   1     2017-03-01 00:00:00.000  20.00  40.00  400.00
10   1     2017-03-01 00:00:00.000  20.00  40.00  400.00
```

En la `opcion1` va acumulando la columna `valor` hasta que hay un cambio de mes. En la `opcion2`, suma los importes de todo el grupo o la partición hecha. En este caso, por mes y cada mes tiene su propio subtotal en la columna `opcion2`.

Comment: Cabe indicar que **por defecto** va a tener `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` que es lo mismo que `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.

Comment: @Davlio amigo como puedo sustituir por 0 donde dice opcion2 y dejar solo el total 400 gracias

Comment: @norma, ¿Quieres que el alias diga `0` y no `opcion2`? al decir `...dejar solo el total 400...`, ¿Quieres filtrar (para el ejemplo de la respuesta) solo para el mes `Enero` (1)?. No te entenderte. :)

Comment: @Davilo en la columna Opcion2 sale del mes de enero sale repetido 400 yo digo como se puede hacer que en vez que se repita se sustituya por 0 o por null para que solo quede el total 400 espero que ,me de a entender

Answer (score 0):

Sugerencia:

1. Insertar en una tabla Temporal tu consulta principal, a esta tabla  agregarle un campo tipo_registro, que va tener dos valores: 'd' detalle, para los registros de tu consulta y luego "t" para los totales que necesitas
2. A la tabla temporal le insertas los totales, simplemente haciendo una consulta a la misma temporal pero agrupando por Mes, el resto de los campo tiene que ir en NULL salvo el tipo_registro = 't', si querés que te quede más lindo, al campo [Puesto] le pones 'Total' + Mes + ':'
3. El resultado final es la misma temporal con los datos de tu consulta más un registro por mes con el total. Para verlos ordenados, simplemente un ORDER BY Mes, tipo_registro.

Te debería quedar algo así:

```
mes    Codigo Area N.Empleado Codigo Puesto     LENTES tipo_registro
====== =========== ========== ====== ============ ====== =============
Marzo  999         AAAAAAAAAA 999999 AAAAAAAAAAAA 100.00 d
Marzo  999         BBBBBBBBBB 999999 BBBBBBBBBBBB 200.00 d
Marzo  999         CCCCCCCCCC 999999 CCCCCCCCCCCC  50.00 d
Marzo  NULL        NULL       NULL   Total Marzo: 350.00 t
```

Comment: en la tabla temporal pongo los datos ya tengo si es asi como vas a ser  cuando haya un mes nuevo?

Comment: La temporal la creas cada vez que emitas esta consulta, con lo cual si hay un nuevo mes no debería haber problema, lo que sí agregaría el número de mes como campo para luego poder ordenar correctamente